# Groupby and count data in existing array to create new reformed array

Tags: javascript

I have an array as follows:

```
[
{customer: bryan, id: 123, consultant: Dave, consultantID: 400}
{customer: sharon, id: 124, consultant: Dave, consultantID: 400}
{customer: bobby, id: 125, consultant: Simon, consultantID: 401} 
{customer: chris, id: 126, consultant: Dave, consultantID: 400} 
{customer: sanji, id: 127, consultant: Lars, consultantID: 402}
]
```

I am trying to create an array that groups the customers by consultant and includes the consultantID as a property like follows:

```
[
{consultant: Dave, count: 3, consultantID: 400}
{consultant: Simon, count: 1, consultantID: 401}
{consultant: Lars, count: 1, consultantID: 402}
]
```

Previously in the project I have been using a [groupby addon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-group-by) to collate information. This works well to count the customers per consultant but I can't take both the name and the ID.

I have tried using a forEach on the array similar to the following:

```
function(){
  let newArray = []
    let patientCount = 0;
    this.get('customerArray').forEach(function(x) {
      let name = x.consultant_name
      let id = x.consultant_id
      let newData = {
        consultantName: name,
        consultantID: id,
      }
      patientCount++
      newArray.push(newData)
    })
    return newArray
}
```

But this gives a return per record (obviously) and I'm unsure how I need to structure this kind of function. I suspect I might need to nest multiple loops but I am unfamiliar with this process as I am new to Javascrtip

Any help is appreciated

Edit: This is the implementation of Denys answer as an Ember Computed property.

```
conTable: computed('conData', function(){
  let array = this.get('conData')
  let grouped = Object.values(array.reduce((s, e)=>{
       let c = s[e.consultantID];
       if (!c) {
             c = s[e.consultantID] = {
                consultant: e.consultant,
                consultantId: e.consultantID,
                count: 0
             };
       }
       c.count++;
       return s;
  }, {}));
return grouped
    }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach for this family of problems is generally to use a map (or an object as map) whose key is the id on which you want to group, and to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array into that map.

```js
let src = [
{customer: "bryan", id: 123, consultant: "Dave", consultantID: 400},
{customer: "sharon", id: 124, consultant: "Dave", consultantID: 400},
{customer: "bobby", id: 125, consultant: "Simon", consultantID: 401}, 
{customer: "chris", id: 126, consultant: "Dave", consultantID: 400},
{customer: "sanji", id: 127, consultant: "Lars", consultantID: 402}
];

let grouped = Object.values(src.reduce((s, e)=>{
     let c = s[e.consultantID];
     if (!c) {
           c = s[e.consultantID] = {
              consultant: e.consultant,
              consultantId: e.consultantID,
              count: 0
           };
     }
     c.count++;
     return s;
}, {}));

console.log("result:", grouped);
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because there aren't so many other methods being used which makes it clearer to read. I have edited the question with the implementation in an Ember computed property. For some reason it returns 'undefined' and I can't work out why, The array is populated and console logging e,c and s returns the objects with the info complete, but the final result is an undefined. console logging C within the If statement produces the grouped array with no count. Is it because some items in the array contain (legitimately) null consultantIDs?

Comment: In typical fashion I just discovered my mistake. I was not returning 'grouped' to the computed property so it was of course blank.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a function with the array, key and wanted properties as parameters and use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for a collection of the same wanted propery.

```js
function groupBy(array, key, properties) {
    var map = new Map;

    array.forEach(o => {
        if (map.has(o[key])) {
            map.get(o[key]).count++;
            return;
        }
        map.set(o[key], Object.assign(...properties.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })), { count: 1 }));
    });
    return Array.from(map.values());
}

var data = [{ customer: 'bryan', id: 123, consultant: 'Dave', consultantID: 400 }, { customer: 'sharon', id: 124, consultant: 'Dave', consultantID: 400 }, { customer: 'bobby', id: 125, consultant: 'Simon', consultantID: 401 }, { customer: 'chris', id: 126, consultant: 'Dave', consultantID: 400 }, { customer: 'sanji', id: 127, consultant: 'Lars', consultantID: 402 }];

console.log(groupBy(data, 'consultantID', ['consultant', 'consultantID']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6

You can also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr=[
{customer: 'bryan', id: 123, consultant: 'Dave', consultantID: 400},
{customer: 'sharon', id: 124, consultant: 'Dave', consultantID: 400},
{customer: 'bobby', id: 125, consultant: 'Simon', consultantID: 401} ,
{customer: 'chris', id: 126, consultant: 'Dave', consultantID: 400} ,
{customer: 'sanji', id: 127, consultant: 'Lars', consultantID: 402}
]

let result = arr.reduce((r, {consultantID,consultant}) => {
    if (!r.some(o => o.consultantID == consultantID)) {
        r.push({consultantID,consultant,count: arr.filter(v => v.consultantID == consultantID).length});
    }
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Note that this implement is much slower on bigger arrays as `some` loops over the elements. It's interesting to display the modern functions but shouldn't be used in real applications.

Comment: there is one more way we can use `[...new Set(arr.map(({consultantID})=>consultantID)]` . This will return only unique  consultantID and we can only loop for the unique consultantID